# How to install Kbackup?

Tags: 18.04, backup, mate, ubuntu-mate

I have 18.04 Ubuntu with Mate.

I looked at `Top 15 Open Source Backup Software for Linux` page on Internet and found, that Kbackup fits my needs: it's a tool with tree inspector with checkbox (gnome has ascetic Deja Dup).

https://www.ubuntupit.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Kbackup.jpg

But how can I install it?
Recommended method `sudo apt-get install kbackup` doesn't work: there is no such package.
Also I noticed that [its package in pre-release freeze status](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kbackup), what does it mean?
Or may be you suggest an alternative?

Comment: According to [this link](https://kdedigest.blogspot.com/2018/04/kde-plasma-gets-kbackup-in-upcoming-version-513-heres-a-quick-look.html), `KBackup` isn't available for Bionic. You'll need to wait for 18.10 which will have KDE Plasma 5.13. Bionic has KDE Plasma 5.12. As for alternatives, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools.

Comment: Also, please note that you need to upload to imgur using the attachment icon above the posting area.

Answer (score 2):

I actually faced the same problem right now, because I upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 only recently. The solution is simple, download the slighly outdated, but functional .deb file that would have been available for xenial. It can be installed with gdebi, or in the terminal with dpkg -i [filename].deb.

Here is the link to choose your prefered repository: https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/xenial/amd64/kbackup/download

This link is for the 64-bit version, but that should be standard by now anyway.

Once kbackup actually becomes available, one can easily remove the manually installed package and get the newest version via apt!